# Getting OperationalError in django

Tags: django, django-models

When i am trying to access the Home page i am getting the following error

OperationalError at /
no such column: articles_article.author_id

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.


class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(default='default.png', blank=True, upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title

    def snippet(self):
        return self.body[:50]+'...'

    def getslug(self):
        return self.title.lower().replace(' ', '-')
```

djangonautic\views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.apps import apps

def about(request):
    return render(request, "about.html")

def home(request):
    article_model = apps.get_model('articles', 'Article')
    articles = article_model.objects.all()[0:3]
    return render(request, "home.html", {'articles': articles})
```

articles\views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Article
from .forms import ArticleForm
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.


@login_required(login_url='users:login')
def article_list(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(request, "articles.html", {'articles': articles })


@login_required(login_url='login')
def article_details( request, slug, pk):
    article = Article.objects.get(pk = pk)
    return render(request, "article_details.html", {'article': article})


@login_required(login_url='login')
def create_article(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            article = form.save(commit=False)
            article.date = timezone.now()
            article.slug = Article.getslug(article)
            article.author = request.user
            article.save()
            return redirect('articles:details', slug=article.slug, pk=article.pk)
    else:
        form = ArticleForm()
    return render(request, 'create_article.html', {'form': form})
```

admins.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Article

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Article)
```

I have run python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate commands but the issue still persists.

0001_initial.py

```
# Generated by Django 3.0.5 on 2020-05-10 18:33

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Article',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('slug', models.SlugField()),
                ('body', models.TextField()),
                ('date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('thumbnail', models.ImageField(blank=True, default='default.png', upload_to='profile_pics')),
                ('author', models.ForeignKey(default=None, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Do you have a migrations directory in your articles app?

Comment: Yes i do. It has the following files
0001_initial.py
__init__.py

Comment: Can you see the column in the DB itself?

Comment: Can you add the contents of the migration file to your question

Comment: I have added the content of Migrations file the question

Answer (score 0):

you need to delete your previous migration files and again run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

it seems you have added new column in existing table.

Comment: Hi Sumeet, I actually did that... but still getting the same issue.

Comment: have you register model table in admins.py file

Comment: yes i have registered. I have added the file content in the original question.

Comment: However, if the table has already been created and you add a field that cannot be null, you have to define a default value to provide for any existing rows - otherwise, the database will not accept your changes because they would violate the data integrity constraints.you can make "null = true" to the added row or give a default value

Comment: wat default value can i give to author field? I want it to be the name of the user that creates it.

Comment: you need to give default name for the records already been save in your db so it dosn't really matter you can give any default it will save for previous data not for the data which will get updated newly .

Comment: I had tried with giving default as 1 but that didnt seem to work. So i just deleted the articles and the db.sqlite3 file and ran migrations again

Answer (score 0):

I guess i solved this issue. I deleted the previously added articles and then i deleted the db.sqlite3 file. Then i ran the migration again and it worked. Not sure if deleting the articles was the correct approach, but that was the only one i could think of.
Please let me know if there was any other way to resolve this error without having to delete the articles.